# How to find Public Plunk without sharing URL

Tags: angularjs

I am new to [Plunker](https://plnkr.co), I am quite familiar with using all functionality it provides. It is quite good. However one thing, I am not sure is how do I make use of Public Plunk, if I saved my page as public, how can I share it with other developers?

I know for the private one, I can send the url to others. If I saved my page as public, it seems the url is changed from 16 chars 5 chars. Also I see from the tool's tip, it suggests "Everyone can see this plunk" for public, I really wonder if I donot share the url of it, how other person can find this splunk?

Comment: Seams it's not there yet...[search plunks feature.](https://github.com/filearts/plunker/issues/43)

Comment: it gives me a light into it. Thank you Diego